# Function returning table is creating public variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am returning a table from a function
First, I am creating a new object type that contains the fields that are going to be returned

```
create or replace type t_col as object (
  i number,
  n varchar2(30)
);
```

Then I am creating a nested table :

```
create or replace type t_nested_table as table of t_col;
```

Then a am creating a function that returns a table

```
create or replace function return_table return t_nested_table as
  v_ret t_nested_table:= t_nested_table();

begin

  v_ret.extend;
  v_ret(v_ret.count) := t_col(1, 'one');

  v_ret.extend;
  v_ret(v_ret.count) := t_col(2, 'two');

  v_ret.extend;
  v_ret(v_ret.count) := t_col(3, 'three');

  return v_ret;
end return_table;
```

The issue is when I am creating a object of type `t_nested_table` in function using following line in the function

> v_ret t_nested_table:= t_nested_table();

Its creating an object like `SYSTPIeQAK45TO9TgUywLAQqu+g==` with public access, other schema users are able to access this object, is there any way to make them private.

Comment: Create a package, wrap the function inside it. Create the type as record and not as an object. An object type resides in the database.

Comment: can you provide some code snippet or some link where I can reference?

Comment: See the answer and the link to documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way to make them private

The only way to achieve that is by:

- Creating a **package**
- Wrap the function inside the package
- Do the **private declaration** in the **package body** and not in the specification.
- Use a **RECORD** type instead of object type. An object type is stored in database.

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/packages.htm#LNPLS009),

> The body holds implementation details and private declarations, which are hidden from code outside the package. Following the declarative part of the package body is the optional initialization part, which holds statements that initialize package variables and do any other one-time setup steps.